# ask for system specifications when asking a questions

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

I thought it might improve the question quality when you ask a question below the question form there is a form asking for your systems specifications. For example version of Ubuntu running, laptop model, network card, processor, Ram etc (feel free to expand upon that list). I think there often are questions like 'my internet is not working, help' it would be useful when people asking questions include some specifications of their system.

I think it would look best when the system info is not collapsed and can be unfolded with a link under the question.

Answer (score 6):

The system does remind people to put as much information in the question that is relevant, many people don't do this though, what I do is add a comment linking them to this question:

- [I have a hardware detection problem, what logs do I need to look into?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into/14126#14126)

And then asking them to add the information. I don't think the SE would add a form to every question as we only really need the information if it's a hardware question.

Comment: Example comment: *We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.* That's the most common comment people use.